# I don't understand the required (matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm in the beginning of matlab course and trying to do some home work; for the next problem I don't understand what's required. any help?

Write a function called bottom_left that takes two inputs: a matrix N and a scalar n, in that order, where each dimension of N is greater than or equal to n. The function returns the n-by-n square array at the bottom left corner of N.

Comment: it's not about Matlab. It's about mathematic and informatic. Informatic part: write a function with 2 inputs: a matrix N and a scalar n, and 1 output: a n-by-n square `matrix`. The mathematic part: matrix N (assume p-by-q) has p >= n and q >= n, and you have to find the n-by-n square matrix at the bottom left cornor of matrix N.

Comment: Hint: define `x = magic(3)`. Then observe `x(1:2,1:2)`. Adapt that to your needs

Comment: Luis means x(1:2,1:2) but his idea is good

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple even for me.

> You have a matrix: [1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16]
>
> and you have a scalar: 2

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

"The function returns the n-by-n square array at the bottom left corner of N"
N=2
therefore
the output is the 2 x 2 array in the bottom left corner:

```
9 10
13 14
```

thats it. The additional info "where each dimension of N is greater than or equal to n" is just to confuse a bit what to do since the input matrix is given and does not needs to be created. Now, being this a homework you can find out how to get such array for any given matrix.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do first is to test if one of the dimensions of your Matrix N (I'm going to assume it's not a square Matrix) is lower than the scalar n. If both of the dimensions are higher then n, then we need to simply put the left lower block of the Matrix N into the variable out. The last operation is done by  Matrix Indexing, which for more information you can visit this [Link](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

```
function [ out ] = bottom_left( N, n )
[m,b]=size(N); % m is number of rows, b is number of columns
if (min(m,b)>=n) % to test if one of the dimensions is lower then the scalar n
    out=N((m-n+1):m,1:n); % extracting the lower left n-by-n bloc from the Matrix by Indexing  
end
end
```

Comment: Okay, at first it throw the dimensions of the Matrix `N` into `m` and `b` , which `m` is the number of the rows and `b` is the number of columns.
Then i make a test to see if the scalar `n` is lesser then the minimum of the two dimensions of `N`. if it is , then i put the bottom left n-by-n Matrix Bloc from the Matrix `N` into variable called `out`.